# How to get the last character typed in a `EditText`?

Tags: android

I want to know when the user types a space character so that I know to update the undo list.

Using `onKeyListener` does not work on virtual keyboards (and is conceptually the wrong approach, I don't care how the user entered the space, he might have pasted it)

`TextWatcher` only provides the full text and taking the last character of the String does not help. The user might as well be typing in the middle. How can I get the last character inserted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: It should take care of it for you.  You may want to add a bit more error checking.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Char at newly inserted pos.
        char currentChar = s.charAt(start + before);  
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Comment: One refinement needed: This results in a StringIndexOutOfBounds error when backspacing at the end of the String. I created a variable called charIndex from start + before, and decremented it as long as it was greater than or equal to the length of the text in the EditText. If the charIndex is greater than -1, then I get the currentChar variable.

Comment: Not a good solution. This solution considers that user can only enter one character. However, if user performs "swipe to type" operation or enters text by using microphone, this solution will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare strings from before and after the `TextChanged` event so that you can see what has changed. This function returns the last char typed or deleted.

`oldStr` is set in `beforeTextChanged` and `newStr` in `onTextChanged`.

This additionally returns the last **deleted** character.

```
public char lastCharTyped(String oldStr, String newStr){
    String shorter, longer;
    //find which string is shorter so that we don't end up out of bounds
    if (oldStr.length()<newStr.length() ) {
        shorter = oldStr;
        longer = newStr;
    } else {
        shorter = newStr;
        longer = oldStr;
    }

    //find the first character that is different and return it
    for (int i = 0; i < shorter.length(); i++) {
        if (longer.charAt(i) != shorter.charAt(i)) return longer.charAt(i);
    }

    //if no characters are different then return the last char of the longer string
    //this means that the undo will be saved if the last char the user erased is a space
    Log.d("longer",longer);
    return(longer.charAt(longer.length()-1));
}
```

Comment: "You can compare strings" Why are you talking to yourself?

Comment: Why are you asking a question and attempting to answer it in the same pen stroke.  See my answer.  simpler then your explanation.

Comment: Because it's [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). But indeed your answer is simpler. I will try it and if it does what I'm asking for I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an answer to 'do something' when a '#'(special character) is entered in text.**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String string = s.toString();
                if(string.contains("#")){
                    //do something
          }
        }

    });
```

Comment: this returns the whole string not the last character typed

Comment: You could make a global string variable and compare both the strings in afterTextChanged to get the last character typed, after comparing don't forget to update the global variable.

Answer (score -2):

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```