# How to get the last word typed in a `EditText`?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I am building a proto social network and I give the possibility to my users to Tag another user with the @ , I'm using an autocomplete textview to show the dialog with the users @  searched but I need to know when a user typed "@" and the letters following in the editext . I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614775/how-to-get-the-last-character-typed-in-a-edittext) and it's exaclty what I need BUT I dont want to only get one character. I want the whole word to make a search in my database . Example, user types "@Jordan" in the middle of his paste text . I need to get the "@" and the "@Jordan " . How can I do it ?

Here s an example of my code

```
 private final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s) && start < s.length()) {


            if (!mentionAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                mentionAdapter.clear();
            }

            String lastWord = s.toString().substring(s.toString().lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
            if (lastWord != null){
                if (lastWord.length() != 0) {


                    switch (lastWord.charAt(0)) {
                        case '#':
                            if (getAdapter() != hashtagAdapter) {
                                setAdapter(hashtagAdapter);
                            }
                            break;
                        case '@':

                            if (getAdapter() != mentionAdapter) {
                                setAdapter(mentionAdapter);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Please send code snippets for us to see what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

I am aiming you are working on android java so here is the answer to your question

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    try {
    String capturedString = getText(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 
});
```

this function will work whenever you tab spacebar "@Jordan " you will get string after '@' and before ' ' means you will get "Jordan" as a string

```
public String getText(String s) {
    String startChar = "#";
    String endChar   = " ";
    String output = getStringBetweenTwoChars(s, startChar, endChar);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

here is getStringBetweenTwoChars function

```
public String getStringBetweenTwoChars(String input, String startChar, String endChar) {
try {
    int start = input.indexOf(startChar);
    if (start != -1) {
        int end = input.indexOf(endChar, start + startChar.length());
        if (end != -1) {
            return input.substring(start + startChar.length(), end);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return input;
}
```

Comment: Its not working its retrieving all the users text , I only need to get the last word typed whatever the position it has been typed

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by following code, If you want to **@java** from the string
**Hello this is @java the best programming language **

```
 edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String str = editable.toString();
            String seperator = "@";
            int seoPos = str.indexOf(seperator);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            boolean found = matcher.find();
            
                if (seoPos != -1 && !found){
                    Log.d("TextChanged0","current Char  "+str.substring(seoPos-1+seperator.length()));
                }
            

        }
    });
```

Comment: Its not working its retrieving all the @Username I typed, I only need to get the last word typed whatever the position it has been typed

Comment: You mean that you want like this eg. Hello this is @java programming. Now you want '@java' from the given sentence is that correct ?

Comment: I had updated the code as per your need. If it helps you please vote me up, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

String last = s.toString().substring(s.toString().lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);